# Why do I have a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers, command-line, command-line-arguments

```
 * Description : This program allows a user to enter a password and and the name of a text file. After the user
 * has entered sufficient information, the program will encode the text and save the overwrite the file with the
 * encoded message.
 *
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char make_lower (char ch){//This converts the text of the selected file to all be lowered
int i;//initializing

    if (isalpha(ch)==1) ch=tolower(ch);//if the selected item in the file is an uppercase character, then it converts it to lowercase.
    else;//other-wise do nothing
    return ch;
}

void randomize ( char arr[], int n, int pswd )//Function that randomizes the alphabet to use while encoding
{
    int i;//initialing
    char ch;//initializing
    // Use a different seed value so that we don't get same
    // result each time we run this program
    srand (pswd);//using the seed the user has entered

    // Start from the last element and swap one by one. We don't
    // need to run for the first element that's why i > 0
    for ( i = 0; i < 26; ++i)//for loop the iterates through the alphabet array
    {
        // Pick a random index from 0 to 25
        int random = rand()%26;

        // Swap arr[i] with the element at random index
        char tmp = arr[random];//swapping
        arr[random] = arr[i];//swapping
        arr[i] = tmp;//swapping
    }}

char encode (char ch, char alpha[]){//function that encodes a message using the alphabet that was randomized
int i, tmp;//initializing

    if (isalpha(ch)== 2){//if the selected character is a lowercase then it gets swapped with the "encoded" character.
    int k = ch;
    ch = alpha[k-97];
}
return ch;}


int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {

    char alpha[26] = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");//initializing char array
    randomize(alpha, 26, argc);
    int i=0;
    char ch;
    while (argv[i] != EOF){
    ch = argv[i];
    ch = make_lower(ch);
    ch = encode(ch,alpha);
    putchar(ch);
++i;
    }
}
```

I don't know why I keep getting the error : Segmentation fault (core dumped).
I believe I have a rogue pointer but I don't know how to fix it. I have used a debugger and still cant seem to fix the issue.

Can someone please help?  Thank you!

Comment: `ch = argv[i];` is an error . You should get compiler messages about this; pay attention to them!  I *think* what you're actually trying to do is to loop over one string that is entered (instead of looping over all strings), you probably meant `while (argv[1][i] != '\0') { ch = argv[1][i]; ` etc.

Comment: Your code doesn't bear much resemblance to the description. You don't use the password entered by the user (instead you use `argc` which is the count of how many arguments there were). You don't attempt to open the file or read the data which is supposed to be encoded, and there's no mention in the description of randomizing anything.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you loop on `argv[]` looking for EOF that you will not encounter.  So your while loop will go out of range as soon as i>=argc.

```
 while (argv[i] != EOF){    // ouch !!! 
   ... // process argv[i]
   ++i;
 }
```

You have to loop on `i<argc` :

```
 for (i = 0; i<argc; i++) { 
     ... // process argv[i]
 }
```

**Other issues:**

As a general practice, define your constant strings like this;

```
char alpha[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; //will automatically get the right length
```

However, the wrong length you've used (forgetting the nul-terminator of the string) is not the cause of your core dump, because in `randomize()` you access to this char array only with variables that are strictly less than 26, and you don't seem to use c-string functions that are depending on this terminator.

Your function `encode()` would also access only to the index 0 to 25 if it would be sure that encoding is done only on lower case chars. Unfortunately, here there is a risk of core dump, because `isalpha(ch)==2` doesn't ensure this : [`isalpha()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/?kw=isalpha) returns a non zero for alphanumerics.  So you'd better use [`islower()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/islower/) instead:

```
if (islower(ch)) { //if the selected character is a lowercase then it gets swapped with the "encoded" character.
    int k = ch;
    ch = alpha[k-97];  // that's fine because if islower() is true k is between 97 and 122 and thus k-97 is between 0 and 25.  
}
```

**Still other minor issues:**

A similar issue is in `make_lower()`  where you should use `isupper()`. But no indexing is used here, so no core dump.

Finally, I wonder if `ch = argv[i];` compiles because argv[i] is a pointer to char.  So you should write `ch = *argv[i];`

Answer (score 2):

your alpha array has 27 elements : 26 (each letters) + '\0' (end of string terminator)

```
char alpha[27] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

You should loop over argc on top of that...

```
for (int i=0;i<argc;++i) {
   f(argv[i]) ....
}
```

Note : your whole program is quite unclear :-)

Comment: I apologize for unclear code... Well I did as you said and it indeed got rid of the segmentation fault, however it is only reading 2 characters within  the file...